# Problem with JSONArray response to android Volley

Tags: php, android, arrays, android-volley

i'm sending this data from php file to android:

[{"Nom_Carrera":"Cursa popular BCN","Ciudad":"Barcelona","Anyo":"2019"},{"Nom_Carrera":"Maraton Madrid","Ciudad":"Madrid","Anyo":"2018"},{"Nom_Carrera":"Mitja Marato Valencia","Ciudad":"Valencia","Anyo":"2018"}]

I know that this is a JSONArray, but how can I parse this data in volley method?

My android code is the following:

```
public void cargarcarreras(String usuario){
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        // Los parametros para el php, hacemos el mapping para poder pasarlo a JSON
        // map.put(KEY, VALUE);
        map.put("uname", usuario);

        // La solicitud JSON
        // JsonObjectRequest(METHOD, URL, JSONOBJECT(PARAMETERS), OK_LISTENER, ERROR_LISTENER);

        request = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST, // the request method
                "http://192.168.1.41:8080/Consulta_Carreras_UnVoluntarioEspecifico_APP.php", // the URL
                new JSONObject(map), // the parameters for the php
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() { // the response listener
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response){
                        // Aquí parseamos la respuesta
                        Log.d("Response", String.valueOf(response));
                        // Aquí parseamos la respuesta

                        JSONObject myJson = response;

                        String resp = null;
                        try { //Comprovamos la respuesta recivida del server
                            resp = myJson.getString("res");
                            if(resp.equals("OK")){//Se ha inciado sesion corectamente
                                //lertmessageLogin(1);
                                //openUserMenu();// Abrimos la activity del menu
                            }
                            if(resp.equals("KO")){//La contrseña que se ha dado es incorrecta
                                //alertmessageLogin(2);

                            }
                            if(resp.equals("KO2")){//El usuario que se ha dado no existe

                                //alertmessageLogin(0);

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() { // the error listener
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { // En caso de error con la conexon con el server entrariamos en esta parte del codigo

                        //alertmessageLogin(4);
                        String vvv="kjdjfbg";

                    }
                });

        // Ejecutamos la solicitud para btener la informcion en formato JSON
        queue.add(request);



    }
```

I have tried putting JsonArray where puts response JSONobject, but it doesn't work. How can I parse the data in order to have it in normal arrays of two dimensions?

Answer (score 3):

Try sending the POST request using `JsonArrayRequest` instead of `JsonObjectRequest`, since the API response is a JSON array

```
 /**
 * Parameters expected for a JsonArrayRequest
 *
 * @param method the HTTP method to use
 * @param url URL to fetch the JSON from
 * @param jsonRequest A {@link JSONArray} to post with the request. Null indicates no parameters
 *     will be posted along with request.
 * @param listener Listener to receive the JSON response
 * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors.
*/

public JsonArrayRequest(
        int method,
        String url,
        @Nullable JSONArray jsonRequest,
        Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener,
        @Nullable Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(
            method,
            url,
            (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(),
            listener,
            errorListener);
}


// Example to make a JsonArrayRequest

// Initialize a new RequestQueue instance
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

            // Initialize a new JsonArrayRequest instance
            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
                    Request.Method.POST,
                    "http://192.168.1.41:8080/Consulta_Carreras_UnVoluntarioEspecifico_APP.php", // the URL
                    null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                            // Process the JSON
                            try{
                                // Loop through the array elements
                                for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                                    // Get the individual json object
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                                                        }
                            }catch (JSONException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                            // Do something when error occurred
                                                      }
                    }
            );

            // Add JsonArrayRequest to the RequestQueue
            requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

Comment: It doesn´t work, the error is the following: Error:(50, 45) error: reference to JsonArrayRequest is ambiguous
both constructor JsonArrayRequest(int,String,JSONArray,Listener<JSONArray>,ErrorListener) in JsonArrayRequest and constructor JsonArrayRequest(int,String,JSONObject,Listener<JSONArray>,ErrorListener) in JsonArrayRequest match

Comment: You're facing that error , since you're sending a json object as a request parameter with JsonArrayRequest which expects a json array object as a post parameter. Hence, send a json array as a post parameter with the request body. Its a clear indication that there is a JsonArrayRequest constructor parameter mismatch. I have updated my answer with the proper sequence of request parameters for JsonArrayRequest in volley, please check that. Probably you also need to modify your webservice to accept parameters in form of a json array from request body. Hope it helps !!